# how to check when field enter/return has been pressed on?

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have multiple fields, typically enter will be pressed on one of the two main ones. I want to know which field enter has been pressed on, how do i do this? (i dont know much JS)

Comment: None of the dups are really dups: 756786 and 1235716 are about blocking (which is specifically not what this question is about), 1248100 is jquery specific while this question is by someone who does not use jquery, and 1364780 is this one.

Answer (score 6):

its simple to add an "onkeypress" event to each of the fields, and then in the event handler to examine the keycode that is attached to the event. For example, consider the following code:

```
form.elements['fieldone'].onkeypress = function(evt) {
   if (window.event) evt = window.event; // support IE
   if (evt.keyCode == 13) alert("Enter was pressed!");
   return true;
}
```

Please note that under most browsers, pressing ENTER in a form field would post that form. If you don't want that to happen, you can simply return `false` from the onkeypress handler and that would tell the browser to ignore that key.

Comment: I do want it to post but i want to know which field enter was hit. If i change a form value will it run before posting the data?

Answer (score 2):

[Check for enter](http://snipplr.com/view/3850/check-for-enter-key-using-jquery/) and set some hidden field (example uses [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$('#input_text').keyup(function(e) {
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('Enter key was pressed.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your page, it should fire automatically when you hit any key and tell you which html element had focus when it happened.

```
<script>
document.onkeypress = KeyPressed;

function KeyPressed(e)
{
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    f ((e.charCode) && (e.keyCode == 13))
    alert('Yay! Enter was pressed while field ' + document.activeElement.id + ' had focus!');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check from which element the event bubbled from using something like the following

```
var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
var text2 = document.getElementById('text2');
text1.onkeypress = keyPresser;
text2.onkeypress = keyPresser;

function keyPresser(e) {
    // to support IE event model
    var e = e || window.event;
    var originalElement = e.srcElement || e.originalTarget;

    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      alert(originalElement.id);
    }
}
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/imoni)**

I would recommend taking a look at the differences in Browser event models and also at unobtrusive JavaScript .

- [QuirksMode - Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [The IE Event Model](http://www.webreference.com/js/column10/)
- [Pro JavaScript Techniques - Unobtrusive Event Binding](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GgJN2CC_2s4C&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=unobtrusive+event+binding+javascript&source=bl&ots=7w2ahV5dLL&sig=ZOsSHgUy2MqSkSIFqrQT8dUuGEQ&hl=en&ei=3JmdSpuZBZTLjAe5jaWeAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=unobtrusive%20event%20binding%20javascript&f=false)

Comment: Event handlers are called in the context of the object where they are attached, so if you're attaching the event handler directly to the wanted objects' onkeypress property, then you can simply look at the `this` reference and it will be the object where the event fired.

Comment: in IE, the this keyword inside of event listener functions points to the window object, not the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) to avoid attaching event handlers to a large number of elements:

```
window.onload = function () {
  document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' && keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Enter pressed on ' + target.id);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Might want to check target.nodeName === "TEXT" too